# Nginx rewrite triggers download

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with creating a simple rewrite url on nginx.
My configuration looks like this:

```
location /foo/bar {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 break;
}
```

E.g. `/foo/bar/baz` should become `/foo/bar/index.php?p=baz` (internally of course)

However, everything accessed through `/foo/bar/` triggers a download of an index.php located at the root. How do I get this to work ?

I've also tried using `try_files` but can't figure out how to exclude the `/foo/bar/` path from `$uri`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 break;
```

to

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
```

Based on http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite,

> last - completes processing of current rewrite directives and restarts the process (including rewriting) with a search for a match on the URI from all available locations.

[Edit] Using break will stay inside the same location block. In your case, there is no other rules inside that location block. So by default, nginx will serve that as a file request.

Comment: np. not sure your rewrite rule serves what you want, though. But using 'last' solves your problem. :)

Comment: @Bart They are the same thing if the rewrite rule is outside the location block. Nginx treats rewrite directive differently inside/outside the location block

Answer (score 0):

The PHP file isn't interpreted and treated as a regular file. You will need to setup a CGI  server like FPM and pass the connection to those processes.

See http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration for details

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure why your example breaks. But my guess is you'll need to change the `rewrite` into a `try_files`.

```
location /foo/bar {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?p=$uri;
}
```

Comment: I can access php files normally anywhere. Just this single rule creates this behavior.

Comment: Do you have more info regarding the server config?

Comment: Not quite sure which info you'll need. I have absolutely no experience with server configuration. A friend set it up for me a while ago. Here is my `nginx.conf` in case it helps: http://pastebin.com/8ubv4Jn4

Comment: I have tried `try_files` before, it works, but the problem with this method is (as stated above) that I can't seem to exclude `~/foo/bar/` from the $uri and I don't necessarily wan't to strip it using php.