# Nginx is dowloading the rewrite file

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have tried the offered solutions:
[Nginx rewrite triggers download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420018/nginx-rewrite-triggers-download)
[nginx rewrite to php file - File is being downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714706/nginx-rewrite-to-php-file-file-is-being-downloaded)

but to no avail.

when I click on the link to `/contact` it just downloads my redirected file.

my config:

```
    rewrite  ^/test$     /index.php last;
    rewrite  ^/contact$  /index.php last;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri = 404; 
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
```

when I visit `/test` it redirects successfully, but when I try and access `/contact` it fails. Accessing php directly works as expected.
I have also tried with the rewrites in the  `location /` block, but I get the same error.

### edit

I have taken out all my redirect rules, and it still downloads my index file.

nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/lib/passenger/;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-head/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    #gzip  on;

    include /opt/nginx/conf/enabled/*.conf;
}
```

/opt/nging/conf/enabled/root.conf

```
server { 
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root   /srv/http/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri = 404; 
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding your rewrites into your location block.

Comment: I already tried that, I get the same thing. edited for clarity

Comment: `default_type  application/octet-stream;` forces the download on mime-types it doesn't recognise. Are you sure your PHP is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if the download is still happening then your php block has something wrong, And if you ask me it's too crowded, I always prefer the most minimal options

```
server { 
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root   /srv/http/public;
    #always place default index in server scope if it's common, check link below
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # check what name exists in your directory fastcgi.conf, or fastcgi_params
        include        fastcgi_params; 
        # make sure this path is correct, otherwise you'll get 502 error.
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html; # < what is this relative to ?
    }
}
```

**PS:** No need for The rewrites for `/content` and `/test` for now since the try_files will handle them.

Link about `index` in locations [Multiple Index Directives](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Multiple_Index_Directives)

Answer (score 1):

> it still downloads my index file.

That's because you're telling it to download your index file here:

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Nginx doesn't magically pass something has a .php extension back through it's processing rules.

If you want to pass all requests through index.php you should just included that in the try_files for the default location.

```
location / {
    try_files      $uri /index.php =404; 
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but why would it then work for example.com/test, and not example.com/contact

Comment: No idea. Maybe either there's something else affecting it in your nginx.conf, or theres a weird typo somewhere.

Comment: This answer worked for me to stop php files from downloading.