# nginx not allowing drop down menus

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, nginx

I was having trouble setting up my php configuration, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147440/nginx-is-dowloading-the-rewrite-file).
Now that I have this fixed, I think that it is causing errors with my dropdown menus.

I am using bootstrap, and when I navigate to bootstraps [example page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/), the dropdown menu works perfectly. When I copy the source code from the website into a sample file on my website, it doesn't work as expected.
(note: the dropdown did work before I changed my config).

If anything else is needed, just say.

current nginx config

```
listen       80;
server_name  hamhut1066.com;
root   /srv/http/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
}
```

Comment: Check the dev tools in your browser to see if your files are being loaded. You may have broken your links.

Comment: my pages are loading, css is fine, php is loading properly. I'm trying it with a php-less page atm, just copy pasted from the sample page then directory to css is changed.

Comment: Because it was working before, and because it works on the bootstrap site, it makes me think that it's a server side issue.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Think about what you're saying. The server is presenting you with a page source - the html and the resources (css). If the server gave you those things (as you just said), then there must be some other problem. Again, be absolutely sure that your page source contains what you expect (html and links), then make sure that all resources are loaded. If so, your html/css usage is incorrect.

Comment: yeah, I know, it's really weird. it works on the home page example.com, but when I go to example.com/test and try, it doesn't work. yet they are exactly the same page

Comment: okay, you were right. I wasn't importing the javascript correctly. sorry about my insistance